# Can I change my music location for itunes to external hard drive on my mac book pro?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music

I have itunes setup with my music in the Music folder on my mac book pro.  I am now realizing that i am going to run out of space soon so i would like to change this to point to an external hard drive.

First question is what is the best way of doing this?

Second question is does this cause a full resync or does it realize that i just moved from one place to another without a required wipe and download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449) for this, there isn't very much to add to it...